# CSS background selectors not applying in html

Tags: html, css

Let me preface with I am a terrible coder and am learning how for school. I have a basic site referencing an external CSS. All other portions of the CSS work except for the background portion. I have tried moving the background image to different folders and trying different file types and I still get nothing. I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and I'm going nuts.

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: url('blackboard.gif');
  color:white
}

.auto-style1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "NACHOS & TV";
  font-size: 55pt;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<head>
  <link href="CSS/RESTAURANT.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>RESTAURANT NAME</title>
  <meta content="RESTAURANT NAME Home Page" name="description" />
</head>
```

Comment: How are your files organized?

Comment: You also have a syntax error in your CSS, add a semi-colon after `color: white`

Comment: @Benjy1996 The semi-colon isn't *required* for the last property...but it is recommended.

Comment: it is in the CSS folder right now, I have tried it in the the main folder and it was originally in the images folder, it did not work in any of them. 
I added the semi-colon after white. There is more markup but I did not want to fill up all the space with it. Want me to post rest of markup?

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't realise that, thought that only applied to inline CSS!

Comment: In that case try this `background: url('css/blackboard.gif');` (assuming your css folder is named "css")

Comment: adding CSS did not work

Comment: What folder is blackboard.gif in?

Comment: currently it is CSS folder. Folder structure for site is: 
Site folder
    has all site pages in it including a copy of blackboard.gif
Images Folder
    has all images including a copy of blackboard.gif
CSS folder
   has CSS an a copy of blackboard.gif

Comment: In case this hasn't been discussed, `url('blackboard.gif')` is looking for an image called `blackboard.gif` in the same directory as the css file. Make sure the image is located there, and that `blackboard.gif` is actually the name (and extension) of the file.

Comment: Do you have the site live to show us on a server somewhere, or is it just on your computer now?

Comment: it's just on my computer

Comment: Besides the background image, it is also not changing the text color, that is what color:white is for correct? Could there be something wrong with the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the url is relative to the css file but if you have trouble, the best is to use a navigator with a developper-tools menu like Chrome (or firebug in Firefox).
With this, you can figure the exact URL used to get this image and fix it.

Comment: background is a shorthand property and it should work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

check the `url()` value in your css `background` property,

if you have the dir structure as:

```
site/
  css/
    restaurant.css
  img/
    blackboard.gif
  index.html
```

you should use:

```
background-image: url('../img/blackboard.gif');
```

so the css renderer will "up" one level directory (because `../`) and search for the img folder.

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out using https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/. The problem was I had a  at the top of my CSS. I am not sure how it got there and I know I did not initially post that, I though it was irrelevant. I apologize and thank you all for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this this should work

```
body {
    background-image: url("your image name");

}
```

Thank you

Comment: `background` is a shortcut for, in this case, `background-image`. Your answer only recreates the original problem.